# Roblox Lua Story Text Code does not change the text locally on the device?

Tags: lua, roblox

This code doesn't work i have everything variabled already tried a script crashhandler, in the variables i typed in the right path so idk why it doesn't work any Help? ROBLOX STUDIO!

```
local Objective = game.StarterGui.BtnLbl.RealObjective

wait(5)
Objective.Text = "Explore the Home"
wait(15)
Objective.Text = "What is that?"
wait(4)
Objective.Text = "RUN!!!"
Objective.TextColor3 = Color3.new(1, 0, 0)
```

I am using a serverside script!

So like i said i tried a script crashhandler but everything worked fine, i was expecting that it would change my Text after 5 seconds to "Explore the Home" then after 15 seconds "What is that?" then after 4 seconds "RUN!!" with the Text being Red, I am using a serverside script!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are changing the text in the StarterGUI.

Every time a player joins, the StarterGUI is cloned into their GUI. The issue is that each player has their own copy that is not affected by the StarterGUI once it has been changed.

What you’ll want to do (if you really want to do it on server) is make a function that loop through every player’s GUI and changes it, something like this:

```
local function updateText(text)
  for i, plr in game:GetService(“Players”):GetPlayers() do
    plr.PlayerGui.BtnLbl.RealObjective.Text = text
  end
end
```